# What exactly is Middlware in redux?

Tags: redux, react-router-redux

Okay so ive been having a hard time understanding middleware and the applyMiddleware in redux and routerMiddleware in react-router-redux. Can some one explain to me what exactly it is in simple terms.
Thank you.

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple layer, which can transform / validate / logg data after `dispatch(someAction(data))` but before handling this action.

Common usages for middlewares is:

- `redux-thunk` - middleware for handling async actions
- `redux-logger` - Logging middleware for each action dispatch
- You also can validate / prevent some actions if they are wrong or not acceptable in current state
- You can transform some data before handling it in action
- You can make some additional requests there, to mix it with dispatched data, but it's a bad practice

You can imagine some other use cases, if you need to do something after each dispatch. For example you can store copies of your current store/state, to be able to revert data in future.

Comment: But what is the use of it? And when do you need to use it? Is there any particular instance where you're supposed to use it? Also can you give me  an example of it.

Comment: It's just a layer to handle some logic before each action, that's all)) You can meet the same abstractions in many frameworks and libraries. As i said, you can use middlewares to validate each action, log information and etc just in one place)) As xiaofan2406 said, look at http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#seven-examples it is a very great article with examples.